# What are the pros and cons of using the Spyridon model of Vibram FiveFingers for climbing?

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, footwear, vibram-five-fingers

So I am moving to Colorado in a little more than three weeks and super-pumped to elevate my experiences with the endless outdoor adventures! At this point in my life, I have six pair of shoes; three traditional style shoes and three different models of the Vibram FiveFingers. I love them. I use them for everything for the past three years or so (as most lovers of these do); running, cycling, everyday walking, hiking.

I am just making plans for further activities with them.

How good is the Spyridon model with climbing?

These seem to be the best choice due to the thicker stiffer sole and the rugged tread design. I really don't want to buy anymore traditional shoes again lol!

Comment: To clarify, do you mean mountain climbing as in mountaineering, or as in rock climbing (which I'm assuming)? Both are quite different.

Comment: No it wasn't difficult to understand whatsoever, yeah it doesn't sound like the best idea to use the Vibrams for climbing! Thanks!

Comment: @NatureRules Would you please clarify the exact use you envision and are inquiring about?  Liam has edited this question to specify *mountaineering* but I am not convinced that was your original intent.

Comment: Did you mean hiking?

Comment: @NatureRules I just ran a marathon in my Five Fingers. I love them.  I also love rock climbing.  Do NOT wear the Five Fingers for rock climbing. Actually, you would figure that out yourself after about 20 seconds of hard climbing. They're the worst.

Comment: With the title saying 'climbing' (which wasn't stated by @NatureRules but we can still use this question) and a pretty good answer I don't think the topic is mainly opinion-based. I vote for a reopen.

Answer (score 6):

Heel hooks and toe hooks will probably hurt...

My biggest concern is due to the individual toes this might make small foot holds uncomfortable. With a traditional climbing shoe the pressure is divided across the sole and all your toes are level inside the shoe.  With a FiveFingers if the toe hold is small such that it's just your big toe on it, that will be a very strenuous move.  I fail to see how you could get support from your other toes.  Sorry if my explanation there is hard to follow, i'm having trouble putting it into words.

I have seen only two people climbing in them at the gym I go to. Give it a go with a pair you own at your local climbing Gym, at least that will bring you closer to a final decision.

Personally I would not recommend climbing outdoors in FiveFingers, I feel they just don't offer the support needed and thus could lead to injury or to an unsafe situation on the rock.

Comment: He means mountaineering not rock climbing.

Comment: @Liam I originally had this as a comment which he then commented where he states "for Climbing".  At that time I moved my comment to an answer.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't the answer OP was looking for. But I thought I'd chime in and point out that indeed, five-fingers are basically the complete opposite of what you're looking for in a climbing shoe. The point of a climbing shoe is to mash your whole foot into one sticky clawlike point.